# Nginx configuration file

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I'm quite new to Nginx and I'm testing out if this is the way to go for me in the future. On my server there are a couple of websites. I managed to set up Nginx correctly. However, on the old setup there was a `.htaccess` file, which made sure all the urls worked correctly.

This is the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^verzekeringen/([a-z]+)$ products/product/index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^hypotheken/([a-z]+)$ products/product/index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^verzekeringen$ products/index.php?type=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^hypotheken$ products/index.php?type=2 [L]
```

An online converter, converted this to:

```
# nginx configuration
location /verzekeringen {
    rewrite ^/verzekeringen/([a-z]+)$ /products/product/index.php?page=$1 break;
}
location /hypotheken {
    rewrite ^/hypotheken/([a-z]+)$ /products/product/index.php?page=$1 break;
}
location = /verzekeringen {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /products/index.php?type=1 break;
}
location = /hypotheken {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /products/index.php?type=2 break;
}
```

In the standard configuration file, there is this part, where **I think** it should be. The problem however, is that I don't really know how to incorporate this into the file.

```
server {
    server_name testwebsite.nl www.testwebsite.nl;

    root /var/www/testwebsite.nl/htdocs;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/testwebsite.nl/htdocs;
        fastcgi_pass   ***.*.*.*:****;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually paste the generated rules as is anywhere before `~ \.php$` rule.

you can also try this folded also :

```
server {
    server_name testwebsite.nl www.testwebsite.nl;

    root /var/www/testwebsite.nl/htdocs;

    location /verzekeringen {
       rewrite ^/verzekeringen/([a-z]+)$ /products/product/index.php?page=$1 break;
    }
    location /hypotheken {
       rewrite ^/hypotheken/([a-z]+)$ /products/product/index.php?page=$1 break;
    }
    location = /verzekeringen {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /products/index.php?type=1 break;
    }
    location = /hypotheken {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /products/index.php?type=2 break;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/testwebsite.nl/htdocs;
        fastcgi_pass   ***.*.*.*:****;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it keeps saying `404 not found`

Comment: Apologies my friend, I didn't interpret the lines for the auto-generated rules, assuming the generator puts good syntax. Try my edit.

Comment: No problem, however, it still keeps throwing a `404` :S

Comment: Sorry again, it seems there is something I missed, I have copied back the generated rules as is, as I indicated in my comments. If this works, then it is my bad, if it does not, then the rules generated are missing something for your side. Let me know please.

Comment: Actually it is the generated code issue, not nginx. Rules logically seem fine, Can you please use cURL from CMD for URLs you get 404 on, and paste them on gist ?

Comment: `<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.0.15</center>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

See directive [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

```
location ~ ^/verzekeringen$ {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ /products/index.php?type=2 last;
 }

 location ~ ^/hypotheken$ {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ /products/index.php?type=1 last;
 }

 location ~ /verzekeringen/[a-z]+$ {
   rewrite ^/verzekeringen/(.*)$ /products/product/index.php?page=$1 last;
 }

 location ~ /hypotheken/[a-z]+$ {
   rewrite ^/hypotheken/([a-z]+)$ /products/product/index.php?page=$1 last;
 }
```